# On full rank matrix properties

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, determinant, finite-fields, matrix-rank

$(1)$ What is number of rank $n$ $m\times n$ $0-1$ matrices when $m=n$ and $m>n$? Is there solutions closed forms?

$(2)$ Over $\Bbb F_2$, does full rank of an $n\times n$ matrix imply determinant is non-zero and vice versa?

Comment: see the answer here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/18636/number-of-invertible-0-1-real-matrices

Answer (score 1):

For $m=n$ you might look at [OEIS sequence A055165](http://oeis.org/A055165) and references there, in particular the [Živković article](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0511636).  Bottom line: there seems to be no known closed form, but there are conjectured asymptotics.

EDIT: For question (2): Over any field, full rank of an $n \times n$ matrix is equivalent to the determinant (evaluated in that field) being nonzero.

Comment: Unable to post new questions due to system block. So updated question with $\Bbb F_2$.